# Asp.net User is in Role but [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] returns Authorization failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, roles, role-base-authorization, .net-core-3.0

So... im trying now for like 2 hours and cant get it to work.

The problem is that if i try to use role based authorization like this

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult createBill() {
    return View();
}
```

no problem at all
but when i try to use it like this

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult createBill() {
    return View();
}
```

I only get Authorization failed. in the Console

i've done this

```
await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
Console.WriteLine(User.IsInRole("Admin")); <- Return true
```

and yes i tried relogging
this is my ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddLiveReload();
    services.AddDbContext<WebinterfaceDbContext>();
    services.AddIdentity<WebinterfaceUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebinterfaceDbContext>();
    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    services.AddMvc(options => { options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build())); }).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin")); });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => { options.AllowSynchronousIO = true; });
}
```

and this is the Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseLiveReload();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

i've used the standard Template of AspNet MVC

I am using these Packages

```
<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.3.0-preview8-19405-04" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview8.19405.11" />
<PackageReference Include="Westwind.AspnetCore.LiveReload" Version="0.1.5.2" />
```

Also netcoreapp3.0
my DbContext

```
public class WebinterfaceDbContext : IdentityDbContext<WebinterfaceUser> {
    public DbSet<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
        builder.Entity<WebinterfaceUser>().Property(e => e.Servers).HasConversion(e => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e), e => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Collection<Guid>>(e));
        builder.Entity<WebinterfaceUser>().Property(e => e.ApiKeys).HasConversion(e => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e), e => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Collection<Guid>>(e));

        builder.Entity<Bill>().Property(e => e.Components).HasConversion(e => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e), e => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Collection<BillComponent>>(e));


        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("User ID=sa;Password=123456;Server=localhost;Database=Webinteface;");
    }
}
```

what also sucks is that the list "Bills" defiend in my Webinterface User is never filled by the Entity Framework..... i dont know anymore what to do its so frustrating to have all these issues.

btw this is my WebinterfaceUser

```
public class WebinterfaceUser : IdentityUser {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string? Company { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public int StreetNumber { get; set; }

    public int Zip { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public Collection<Guid> Servers { get; set; } = new Collection<Guid>();

    public Collection<Guid> ApiKeys { get; set; } = new Collection<Guid>() {Guid.NewGuid()};

    public Guid SupportApiKey { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public Collection<Bill> Bills { get; set; } = new Collection<Bill>();

    public List<Bill> getBills() {
        return new WebinterfaceDbContext().Bills.Where(b => b.Recipient == this).ToList();
    }

    public List<Server> getOwnedServers() {
        ServerContext context = new ServerContext();
        return context.Servers.Where(s => Servers.Contains(s.Guid)).ToList();
    }

    public Server getServerByGuid(Guid guid) {
        return getOwnedServers().Find(s => s.Guid == guid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I just ran into this exact problem. It's because of some changed behavior with the authorization in dotnet core 3.0.

According to [Microsoft's migration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorization) you have to put app.UseAuthorization() AFTER app.UseAuthentication(). Once you do that the Authorize roles should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will test will this when i have enough time to test this in a newly created project. I already fixed this by using another routing thing instead of the default mvc routing. I dont know how it called right but its just a workaround anyway